# How to disable a button without affecting any other component?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

Hey i am trying to disable my button after a single click. What this button does is, it should display the slider after its clicked and then it should become disable to avoid further display of slider one over another.
What i have dome is i have allocated a tag to button and accessing it in the buttoncliked method and doing button.enabled = NO;. But what its doing is making the slider disable also.

Any suggestions?

```
int tag = [sender tag]- kselectTag;
    UIImage * buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scenariosButtonsSmallTap1.png"];
    UIImage * strechableButtonImage = [buttonImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [_select setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSDictionary * step = [[_currentDict objectForKey:[[_currentDict objectForKey:@"Selectable"]objectForKey:@"Step1"]]retain];
    NSString * frameS = [step objectForKey:@"FrameS"];
    CGRect frame1 = CGRectFromString(frameS);
    NSString * frameString = NSStringFromCGRect(frame1);

    NSString * frameB = [step objectForKey:@"FrameB"];
    CGRect frame2 = CGRectFromString(frameB);
    NSString * frameString1 = NSStringFromCGRect(frame2);
    NSNumber * place = [step objectForKey:@"placeP"];
    int p = [place intValue];
    NSString * boxImage = [step objectForKey:@"BoxImage"];
    NSString * min = [step objectForKey:@"IntLabel"];
    NSString * max = [step objectForKey:@"LstLabel"];
    int mn = [min intValue];
    int mx =[max intValue];
    //UIImageView * back2 = (UIImageView*)[bubble2 viewWithTag:151187];
    _select = (UIButton*)[_select viewWithTag:tag];
    [_select setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [self addSliderBox:[UIImage imageNamed:boxImage] andFrame:frameString1];
    [self addSliderX:frameString andminimumValue:mn andmaximumValue:mx andSliderValue:p];
```

Comment: what about `myButton.userInteractionEnabled`?

Comment: If you disable the parent view all subviews will be disabled too. So don't add the slider to the button as subview.

Comment: i am adding slider to self and not to the button

Comment: @ Deepak: That will make button go invisible. I want it to be there but not active.

Comment: Yes, I am interested to know how it affects the slider.

Comment: That will not effect in anyway.

Answer (score 2):

try    `button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

Edit :

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[_select viewWithTag:tag];
NSLog(@"%@", btn); // Check if btn is really your `UIButton`, if not check your `tag`
[btn setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: i tried that too and this is aslo doing the same thing making button + slider disable.

Comment: can you edit your post and send us where do you disable your UIButton, I don't understand why your UISlider is disable too...

Comment: @Ashutosh: Please post your solution here as an answer so that others can benefit from it.